# How is it possible to make a cross domain AJAX call between two subdomains on the same site?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I want to make an AJAX call from www.mysite.com to api.mysite.com.
Is this possible?

I've ready about document.domain, but as far as I can tell thats only good for cross DOM communication, such as through an iframe.

I'm also aware of CORS but am looking for a subdomain-specific solution, if there is one.

I looked at other questions before asking here and the only solutions I found were CORS (which I prefer not to use as the solutions I found for NGINx to do his were marked experimental) and proxies, which I don't want either for server load reasons.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: My first thought, without writing any code, is this should be possible since it is a sub-domain.  Have you tried this and gotten errors?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7736250/27862 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/27862

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I've updated the question: I looked at other questions before asking here and the only solutions I found were CORS (which I prefer not to use as the solutions I found for NGINx to do his were marked experimental) and proxies, which I don't want either for server load reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648899/a-question-about-cross-domain-subdomain-ajax-request) is almost the same question. You have three options:

1. iframe + document.domain (see link above for details)
2. set up proxy to redirect all request from www.mysite.com/api to api.mysite.com (to avoid cross-domain (or subdomain) issue completely)
3. use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: Thanks, but I need another solution if possible. An iFraem is very messy and problematic, the proxy is a problem due to server load reasons and jsonp doesn't solve my need for POST.