# Would requesting a page from a subdomain via AJAX work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, subdomain

I'm writing a userscript to be run on youtube video pages. It needs to make requests to gdata.youtube.com using jQuery to make things easier. Would this work or does it violate the cross-domain policy?

Comment: Seems there are a [few suggestions](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+ajax+document.domain) out there but the world seems to change with each new version of each browser

Comment: This one seems a good collection of suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735955/cross-subdomain-ajax-request-denied-even-when-document-domain-is-set-correctly

Comment: Userscripts on chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936639/cross-origin-xhr-from-a-user-script-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it violates the cross-domain policy because you're not hosting it on youtube.com, so domain or subdomain, its still not the domain the script is located on so it wont work.