# jQuery - Send a cross-domain PUT/DELETE request

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, http, cors

I have 2 sub-domains: **main.example.com** and **api.example.com**

Both sit on the same machine.

I am trying to send **PUT/DELETE** requests from **main.example.com** to **api.example.com** but it won't let me do it.

Response headers, from **api.example.com**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://main.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

This is how the request is made:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.example.com/script.cgi',
    type: 'PUT',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

It throws me an error:
**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.example.com/script.cgi. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.**

How can I fix this? I wasted the whole day in trying to fix it but without success.

P.S. does not work in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Try adding `access-control-allow-headers` header

Comment: and which headers exactly i have to add?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735955/cross-subdomain-ajax-request-denied-even-when-document-domain-is-set-correctly

Comment: try `origin`, `content-type`, `accept`, `x-requested-with`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to add the CORS headers on the preflight (OPTIONS) response **and** on the PUT response.

I tested your setup (only `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`) and everything works as soon as the two responses have the CORS headers (if I remove them from the PUT response for example, I get your error).